# What does this do: `const { $ } = require("@rails/ujs");` within my Rails app? It seems to be causing an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-ujs

in `app/javascript/packs/application.js` I see: `const { $ } = require("@rails/ujs");`

For some unknown reason, I get this error:

```
rails-ujs.js:73 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '[object HTMLDocument]' is not a valid selector.
    at ./node_modules/@rails/ujs/lib/assets/compiled/rails-ujs.js.Rails.$ (http://192.168.1.34:3000/packs/js/application-82ae508a0043ae1b2583.js:1497:52)
    at Object../app/javascript/packs/application.js (http://192.168.1.34:3000/packs/js/application-82ae508a0043ae1b2583.js:207:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://192.168.1.34:3000/packs/js/application-82ae508a0043ae1b2583.js:20:30)
    at http://192.168.1.34:3000/packs/js/application-82ae508a0043ae1b2583.js:84:18
    at http://192.168.1.34:3000/packs/js/application-82ae508a0043ae1b2583.js:87:10
```

When I comment out the line: `const { $ } = require("@rails/ujs");` - then the error goes away, but I don't know if I need this line or not?

This error wasn't happening before... wish I had more details, but I don't.

Comment: The Rails UJS handler provides the functionality for links with the `data-method` option, confirmations, and ajax with `remote: true` on forms and links. `require` is a directive for webpacker that imports the dependency in your pack. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: Have you tried looking at github to see if this is tied to an issue with your version of Rails? The most likely cause here is that there is some code here that expects `$` to be jQuery and its instead using the native  `querySelectorAll` which does not accept an object like jquery.

Comment: @max ok, I think it might be because I'm putting my app logic in `application.js`, it looks like I'm supposed to put my app logic into packs, and then import it into `application.js`, is that right? I think that might be why I'm getting the error. I'm writing code that uses the `$` symbol as if it's jQuery, and I'm putting that logic into `app/javascript/packs/application.js`, just doing that out of convenience, but perhaps I'm not supposed to do that?

Comment: Well for starters don't use Rails UJS as if it where jquery. The latest version does not depend on jquery. I don't think you really need to assign the module to the constant `$` here. Not sure why thats done in the first place.

Comment: If you do want to use jQuery and avoid conficts just use an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression). `(function($){ // code goes here }(jQuery));`.

Comment: @max seems that's how it was by default... I'm pretty sure I didn't add it.

Comment: I put all of my application specific JS into its own javascript pack, and then included it after the application pack, and no more error and everything works